# Encoding issue on Azure WebJobs

Tags: c#, azure, encoding, azure-webjobs

I followed Scott Hanselman's [Introduction on Azure WebJobs](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingWindowsAzureWebJobs.aspx) and created a little C# program to play with it.

My program is really simple (download an XML file, parse it and call a web service with the data extracted from the XML). The problem is that I noticed there was a random bug happening. 
It looked like every time my data had a string that contained an accent, the web service call silently failed. So I took a look at the Azure WebJobs logs and noticed that there was something weird with accented characters.

I simplified my code to the maximum: here is the program I sent and executed on Azure:

```
using System;

namespace TestAccents
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("e é à a");
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the result on the Azure logs:
[image: azure webjob encoding problem]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this looks like a bug. I opened https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/1418 to track it. You may want to follow that issue to track resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Since the bug is still not corrected, here is the **workaround** I currently use (but still waiting for a real correction): 
**Replacing the non diacritics characters by their corresponding diacritic form**

```
using System.Text;
using System.Globalization;
```

**Function**

```
static void ConsoleWriteLineNoDiacritics(string stIn)
{
    string stFormD = stIn.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < stFormD.Length; i++)
    {
        UnicodeCategory uc = CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(stFormD[i]);
        if (uc != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
        {
            sb.Append(stFormD[i]);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
}
```

**Usage**

```
ConsoleWriteLineNoDiacritics("Test é ç à è");
```

**Result**

```
[12/01/2016 10:20:13 > xxxxx: INFO] Test e c a e
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi it's late but you can change the output Console encoding by addind this line of code at your're beginning program :

```
//UTF16 was default output and Azure Console doesn't support this
             Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
```